# Eclipse merge tool is overwriting my changes

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

The eclipse merge tool is not behaving as expected for me.

It is overwriting my ***local changes*** as well as merging the remote changes.

I double click on a conflicted file (or open merge tool via right click)

[image]

A typical scenario might be where I have some local changes that are marked as gray :

[image]

Incoming changes look the same but are blue :

[image]

Then I click on "Copy all non conflicting changes from right to left", (ie this button) :

[image]

I would expect only the blue changes to move from right to left. All the blue changes are moved to the right, HOWEVER all the gray changes are also overwritten from what is on the right!!!

Why is this happening?? Is this a known bug?

What is also strange is that the gray and blue diff graphics in the scroll bar still remain even if I have copied all changes from right to left.

It is saying there is a difference there even when there is not :

[image]

Comment: Which Eclipse version do you use? This sounds like the bug that has been fixed in Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a), as you can see in my video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=388s

Answer (score 1):

This sound like [**Eclipse bug 519390**: "Copy All Non-Conflicting changes from Right to Left" overwrites local changes](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=519390) **which has been fixed** in Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a).

Upgrading (***Help > Check for Updates***) should fix the problem.

See also my [video showing the error as well as the fixed *Compare Editor*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wI3VC1lhbK8&t=388s).